# how to create payload field in laravel jobs table

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

According to this link, a record is created for the job table.

[enter link description here](https://divinglaravel.com/preparing-jobs-for-queue)

I want to create a payload field with the insert mysql command in Trigger or Procedure and anywhere else in the database.

How can I do this?

payload objects are

```
protected function createObjectPayload($job)
{
    return [
        'displayName' => $this->getDisplayName($job),
        'job' => 'Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler@call',
        'maxTries' => isset($job->tries) ? $job->tries : null,
        'timeout' => isset($job->timeout) ? $job->timeout : null,
        'data' => [
            'commandName' => get_class($job),
            'command' => serialize(clone $job),
        ],
    ];
}
```